# Send message to another machine on local network using MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

I want to write  application that send message to another machine in the network using MSMQ and found this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/6897bc/understanding-and-using-msmq/
i try to senf the message and i can see my message in the `Queue` but from the other machine how can i catch this message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308668/writing-to-a-remote-msmq ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure MSMQ service is running on the other machine. Also, the service might bind itself to 127.0.0.1 on windows 7... You may just try to restart the service on the other machine...

Comment: Baral right. most common mistake is forgetting to install MSMQ service on all the machines that will listen or send. as for binding you can configure that in one of the tools in control panel / administrative tools. As for installing with an application there is a silent install that exist. i am not the one that implemented it but it was in one of our software at my last job